# Port forwarding stops abruptly - Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, port-forwarding

You can port-forward in windows, like so, [this is explained in this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525703/port-forwarding-in-windows).

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=80 listenaddress=192.168.1.111 connectport=80 connectaddress=192.168.0.33
```

I did this, and it works.

Randomly - sometimes once a month, or even after I just restarted the server, the port forwarding just stops abruptly.

It just stops listening entirely on port 80 - can't telnet - can't do anything - totally out of the blue.

After messing around a bit, I finally delete the port forwarding:

```
netsh interface portproxy delete v4tov4 listenport=80 listenaddress=192.168.1.111
```

And then re-create it:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=80 listenaddress=192.168.1.111 connectport=80 connectaddress=192.168.0.33
```

This was working again for a while, and recently not even this has been working. The only solution when this happens is that I have to restart the server!

This is a *production* server and I can't have this just dropping out. No way. Does anyone have any idea of what to check to find the cause and handling of this? I can find no articles online that cover this.

Comment: Do the event logs say anything?

Comment: Also make sure your power policy is set for high performance and that your NIC is never allowed to go into power saving mode. You didn't tell us anything about your hardware, so you may have vendor-specific NIC settings that you can configure too.

Comment: @Ryan thanks. Everything else on the server is fine, and the regular TCP/IP connections work fine. It *only* stops listening on port 80, but every other connection that is not the result of the port forwarding works fine.

Comment: Can you grab a packet capture on the server to see if traffic is 1) reaching the server, and 2) actually forwarding out? You may be running into some kind of network-related issue. Also, just curious (since I've never actually used this feature) if anyone else or you have ever used this feature for extended periods of time with success?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've installed the IPv6 protocol if it's working at all?

I suspect this is a NIC driver problem, I would try swapping them.

Answer (score 0):

When it shut down did you run the SHOW v4tov4 command to see if it was still in the dll? I'm wondering if something overwrote that file (did you restart, or update, or install a new role?).